# How to solve this probability problem related to numbers of a lottery?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

> In a simple lottery the organiser chooses three numbers at random
>   without replacement from the numbers 1 to 5. Players also choose three
>   numbers without replacement from the numbers 1 to 5.

**Calculate the probability that a player matches two or three of the organiser’s numbers.**

**What I tried-**

5C3 ways to choose three numbers i.e 10 ways to choose three numbers. After that I can't proceed.

Comment: As there are only ten combinations for each, you could make a 10×10 table and count the hits by hand; in the process you might get an insight.

Answer (score 1):

Add up the following:

- The probability that a player matches exactly $\color\red2$ numbers, which is $\dfrac{\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot\binom{5-3}{3-\color\red2}}{\binom{5}{3}}=\dfrac{3}{5}$
- The probability that a player matches exactly $\color\red3$ numbers, which is $\dfrac{\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot\binom{5-3}{3-\color\red3}}{\binom{5}{3}}=\dfrac{1}{10}$

Comment: the answer gives the combined probability...  How to get it. Do I have to add these two?

Comment: @CodeProcessor: I don't understand your question.